# How to expose an resource like downloadable link in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cordova-plugins

Actually I have a spring boot server with many files in resource folder (src/main/resources/public/myfilefolder/myfiles.apk). Well my requirement is to download a file with cordova file transfer library. My first idea was put the resource link directly in the component:

```
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var fileURL =  "///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myFile";
var uri = encodeURI("http://myserver/src/main/resources/public/myfilefolder/myfiles.apk");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("download error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {

      /*
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }

        */
    }
```

But obviously doesn´t work well, because the server think that it´s a controller route. Any ideas to expose this resource to be downloadable?

Comment: The URL is `http://myserver/myfilefolder/myfiles.apk`. Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Yes men.... this was the solution, ty for save my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. Thank´s for the answers, this is my solution:

In your spring boot server you need this method:

```
@GetMapping(value="/file_download",

produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
  )
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource downloadFile(@RequestParam String filename) throws IOException{

//to consume http://youserver/file_download?filename=mytest

try{


  System.out.println("in file download " +filename);

   String path = "src/main/resources/public/makingAPK/"+filename+"/"+filename+".apk"; //path of your file


    return new FileSystemResource(new File(path));
}

catch(Exception e){System.out.println("error in file_download "+e); return null;}

}
```

And in your cordova plugin transfer:

```
$scope.DownloadFileFromServer = function(url){ //file server location


   var fileURL =  "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/thefile.apk";

try{

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://yourserver/yourCtrlName/file_download?filename=yourfilename");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("download error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {

      /*
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }

        */
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a get request in springboot app where you can pass your file name and it will download the file as based on input, you can add restriction on download based on your application requirement.

```
@GetMapping("/downloadResource")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadResource(
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = DEFAULT_FILE_NAME) String fileName) throws IOException {

    MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName(this.servletContext, fileName);

    MediaType mediaType = // Get media type of file
    System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);
    System.out.println("mediaType: " + mediaType);

    Path path = Paths.get(DIRECTORY + "/" + DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            // Content-Disposition
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + path.getFileName().toString())
            // Content-Type
            .contentType(mediaType) //
            // Content-Lengh
            .contentLength(data.length) //
            .body(resource);
}
```